# only show on facebook meta property="og:image"

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having a problem using `meta property = "og: image"` to facebook, I need you when content is shared through me display only those images that are in the `meta property = "og: image"` and we who are `img` as `href`, not if I'm doing wrong, please I need help.

Link to the problem:

http://desa.uchile.cl/noticias/92894/beauchefiana-blanca-duran-se-corono-campeona-nacional-de-tenis-mesa

the html source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="blog" />
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://desa.uchile.cl/u/ImageServlet?idDocumento=92894&indice=0"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://desa.uchile.cl/u/ImageServlet?idDocumento=92894&indice=1"/>           
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Beauchefiana Blanca Durán se coronó campeona nacional de tenis mesa - FCFM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/u/portlets/herramientas/herramientas.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/u/framework/skeletons/FCFM/images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/u/framework/skeletons/FCFM/css/screen.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css_fcfm/screen2.css">
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://desa.uchile.cl/noticias/92894/beauchefiana-blanca-duran-se-corono-campeona-nacional-de-tenis-mesa">      
</head>

<header>
  <section id="nav">
  <div id="banner">
    <a href="/" title="Portada Facultad de Ciencias Físicas y Matemáticas">
        <img alt="Facultad de Ciencias Físicas y Matemáticas" src="/u/framework/skeletons/FCFM/images/logo-fcfm00.png" />
    </a>
  </div> 

  </nav>
 </header>
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdesa.uchile.cl%2Fnoticias%2F92894%2Fbeauchefiana-blanca-duran-se-corono-campeona-nacional-de-tenis-mesa

Comment: this is a problem that arises from my web sharing through add_this